# Why do I need geany_run_script.sh in every project directory?

Tags: geany

I develop web applications (in PHP, JavaScript, CSS) using Geany, so I'm in no need for compile, run, make... functions of Geany. Yet Geany is spamming my project directories by creating geany_run_script.sh file in every one of them.

The question is: What can I do to make it stop doing this?

Comment: Can not reproduce, but I remember seeing an option for that somewhere, maybe in another version of Geany on my computer at work. What version are you using?

Comment: @tobias_k I use the latest 1.23.1. It sure would be nice to have a checkbox for that.

Comment: I filled a bug report on it at https://sourceforge.net/p/geany/bugs/975/ 
The "sad" thing is, that I can't reproduce it anymore (for now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need it. You can configure it via Preferences->Terminal->Execute programs in VTE + Don't use run script. This will need you to have libvte installed and will not work at Windows.

These scripts are generated once you hit F5 e.g. for previewing it inside a browser.